# Install airflow package extras in PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, airflow

I want to use [Airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/) package [extras](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#installing-setuptools-extras) `s3` and `postgres` in PyCharm but do not know how to install them (on macOS Sierra).

### My attempts so far

Airflow itself can be installed from **Preferences** > **Project** > **Project interpreter** > **+** but not the extras as far as I can work out.
The extras can be installed with `pip` in the terminal using

```
$ pip install airflow[s3,postgres]
```

but they end up in a different interpreter (`~/anaconda`) than the one used by PyCharm (`/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`).

Checking the Python executables in my `/usr/local/bin` directory I found that only `pip3` and `pip3.5` point to the PyCharm interpreter, but `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7` do not.

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep pip
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root        admin       204 Dec 21 11:41 pip
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root        admin       204 Dec 21 11:41 pip2
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root        admin       204 Dec 21 11:41 pip2.7
lrwxr-xr-x    1 christofer  admin        34 Nov 21 11:53 pip3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/bin/pip3
lrwxr-xr-x    1 christofer  admin        36 Nov 21 11:53 pip3.5 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/bin/pip3.5
```

Browsing the directory of the PyCharm interpreter I found all the expected python executables (`python`, `python2.7` etc.) pointed to from `/usr/local/bin` but no `pip`.

### What I need help with

So, the problem could be solved if I/you/we can figure out either

1. how to install `airflow[s3,postgres]` from within PyCharm, or
2. how to run `pip install airflow[s3,postgres]` pointing to the PyCharm interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, the problem could be solved if I/you/we can figure out either
>
> 1. how to install airflow[s3,postgres] from within PyCharm, or
> 2. how to run pip install airflow[s3,postgres] pointing to the PyCharm interpreter.

Or maybe?:

3. Add the `~/anaconda` Python to Pycharm

To add another python interpreter to Pycharm goto:

```
File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Interpreter
```

Press the Gear Button and select `more`:

[image]

This shows all of the interpreters configured.  Select the `+` button, and select `add local`:

[image]

Now you should be able to add your anaconda Python to Pycharm.  You can then select which Python to use as primary for the project, and you can select which Python to run under:

```
Run -> Edit Configurations
```