# Can't import package installed with PIP

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-3.6

**Problem**

I'm not new to programming, however I am new to Python. I am attempting to import a package called GDAX in regards to Coinbase's GDAX market. I've installed it using `pip install gdax`, and `python -m pip install gdax` per solutions I have found online similar to my issue.

The package is installed successfully in both cases, however, when I create my new project in PyCharm, and try `import gdax`, it's not found. I've tried several different keyword searches to find a solution for my problem, but have yet to find one. I've searched for generic tutorials on how to install packages not included in python, and it seems like what I've done to install the package is correct.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, or what I'm missing?

Comment: Try installing via PyCharm->Settings->Python Interpreter

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm looking at PyCharm->File->Settings->Search "interpreter", and it just takes me to "Project: GDAX Test">Project Interpreter". Nothing to do within this screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982661/install-airflow-package-extras-in-pycharm/41991633#41991633, from this page, you can also add packages to an interpreter.

Comment: @StephenRauch adding Local Python Interpreter, this time, enabling Inherit global site-packages has resolved my issue. Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: @JesseA consider accepting the answer if it did resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

**Enabling Inherit global site-packages has resolved my problem**

To add/edit a Python interpreter in PyCharm goto:

```
File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Interpreter
```

Press the Gear Button and select `more`:

[image]

This shows all of the interpreters configured.  From here you can add/edit the Virtual Enviroments.

> If you want the site-packages of the base interpreter to be visible from the virtual environment, select the check box Inherit global site-packages. If you leave this check box cleared, the new virtual environment will be completely isolated.

([PyCharm Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-virtual-environment.html))